# jquery ui sortable receive(e,ui), how do I get a child of the incoming element so that I can show() it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the receive event for my sortable list, I need the event to be able to change the style of one of the child elements of an element when it is dragged in from a draggable. Here's a simplified example:

```
    <ul id="sortable">
      <li>element1<div class="child"></div></li>
      <li>element2<div class="child"></div></li>
    <ul>

    <ul id="draggable">
      <li>element3<div class="child"></div></li>
      <li>element4<div class="child"></div></li>
    <ul>
```

With JS:

```
    $('#sortable').sortable(
    {
          //extra stuff excluded

              receive: function(e, ui)
                         {
                            //how do I use ui to get the child element "child"?
                            //also I need to be able to style the current li element
                         }
    }
);

    $('#draggable').draggable(
            {
          connectToSortable: '#sortable'
            }
    );
```

**Problem Solved: Answer is posted below by Frédéric Hamidi, but in short, the answer is to use the stop event rather than the receive event on the sortable.*

Comment: Please do a console.log(ui); within receive function and post what it returns

Comment: Can you please create jsFiddle for the same??

Comment: "Receive triggers when a connected sortable list has received an item from another list."

Comment: here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spensimon/PeS2D/337/ It seems to work with a solution posted below, but my main issue is it does not change the child element on the newly dragged element, but on the old original element. I need the newly dragged element to have the child changed. My setup is basically the same as this, so I need the original element to stay so that it can be dragged over several more times (there will be duplicates)

Answer (score 4):

In the `receive` event, `ui.item` will contain a jQuery object wrapping the dragged element. You can use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) or [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to match its child element:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    receive: function(e, ui) {
        ui.item.css("color", "red");        // For example.
        ui.item.children(".child").show();  // Show child <div>.
    }
});
```

*Update:* Since you're using a cloned helper, you could use `ui.helper` instead of `ui.item`. However, that doesn't seem to give good results (maybe because the helper originates from another widget).

Another solution is to handle the `stop` event instead of `receive`. There, `ui.item` is always the new element, regardless of helper options:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    helper: "clone",
    items: "li",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        ui.item.children(".child").show();
    }
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PeS2D/338/).

Comment: hey, here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spensimon/PeS2D/337/ I need the copied dragged elements to be the one having the child element shown though, in this case, the original draggable child elements are the ones being effected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Indeed, the cloned helper complicates things a little. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's definitely what I was looking for! Looks like I will have to move some stuff around in my code, but I think I can get it to work the way I want it to. Any idea on changing the css of the ui.item? I put "ui.item.css("color", "red");" in there and it still changes the original, not the new element?

Comment: @ytudfollac, strange, `ui.item.css(...)` works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeS2D/339/)). Which browser are you using?

Comment: haha, sorry about that, I actually pasted into the wrong fiddle! works now. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution ! Thumbs up (y)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ui.item property. From jquery.ui specification: ui.item - the current dragged element.

```
receive: function(e, ui){
             var content = $(ui.item).children('div.child').html();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stop function on the Sortable Plugin to access the Item that is being placed in the list.

```
$('#sortable').sortable(
{
    stop: function( event, ui )
{
    $(ui.item).html('your content here');
}
});
```